# What's the correct way to handle new breeze entities that might be thrown away?

Tags: breeze

I'm sure I've created my own pain here, but I'm struggling to understand the correct sequence of events to manage creating new entities in my scenario.

In my model I have two objects, **ObjectA** and **ObjectB** that both inherit from **BaseObject**, obviously each with their own additional properties.

In my view, as most of the information is the same, I want the user to be able to just select an option as to which one to create.  So they fill out **SharedProperty1** and **SharedProperty2 (which is a collection navigation property)**, select an option as to if they want an A or B object, and then fill in a final page which has the last object specific properties.

As I didn't know which entity to create until the user had selected this option, I built a an object in the viewmodel to handle this temporary data.  As part of that while they are filling out **SharedProperty2 (the collection)**, as they add new **ChildObjects**, I create them with `entityManager.createEntity('ChildObject')`.  Then when they reach the end, I create either **ObjectA** or **ObjectB** entity and add the child entitites (and other properties) and then try and save.

The problem is it never saves correctly, but I get different results depending on which approach I take.  So because the user could just abort the new object process, I was creating the **ChildObjects** with `EntityState.Detached` because I thought that would be easier if they got thrown away.  I realised though that all the entities created in this way get the id key 0.  So then I fixed the keys while I was adding the **ChildEntites** to the parent (either **ObjectA** or **ObjectB**), by assigning them decreasing negative numbers (ie: -1, -2, etc).  This resulted in some crazy server-side behaviour with only some entities being saved to the db and complaints of conflicting foreign keys.

This also had a bad smell that I hadn't understood this correctly, and I'd made a mess of it.  So now I tried just creating the entities normally (ie: without the `Detached` flag), and they all get their own unique keys (again breeze appears to follow -1, -2, etc), but now when I try to copy them from my temporary viewmodel collection to the parent object collection, I get the error that `an entity with this key is already attached`.  So now I can't even build up the correct model to save.

I still think I've not understood quite correctly how to handle this, so some pointers would be deeply appreciated.

---

To head off what I suspect will be a question, why I didn't use RejectChanges to handle the entities being thrown away.  Basically a user can add a ChildObject (object gets created by breeze entityManager, added to viewmodel collection, bound to UI), and then decide to just remove it again (currently just gets removed from viewmodel collection) before they save their data. If I used reject changes I would throw away other important entites.  I think I'm now going to be a good boy and use the proper detach method if someone removes the ChildObject in the view.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create some properties and then add them to a parent objects collection when saving.  Correct me if I am wrong, but Breeze not only supports this, but does so *very* efficiently.  Having come from .NET and C# it was very difficult for me to grasp how easy this can be, but this is what I would do if I were you -

```
var childA = ko.observable();
var childB = ko.observable();

childA(entityManager.createEntity('ChildObject')); // populate your children
childB(entityManager.createEntity('ChildObject')); // populate your children
```

Then you can edit them in your view, and when you are ready to save simply add them to the collection.

```
var save = function() {
    isSaving(true);
    var parent = ko.observable();
    return entityManager.getParent(parent, parentId)
            .then(setParents)
            .fail(catchError);

    function setParents() {
        childA().parent(parent());
        childB().parent(parent());
        entityManager.saveChanges()
                .then(complete)
                .fail(catchError);

        function complete() {
            isSaving(false);
            return Q.resolve();  // Don't know if you have any unresolved conflicts
        }
    }  
};
```

Basically in this manner we are -

A : Creating the entities
B : Editing them without performing any changes
C : When we call save we are setting their parent navigation property.  In my prior ways (be it right or wrong) I would have simply set ParentId(parentId) and let EF figure out how to navigate but (pardon the pun) this is a breeze with Breeze.  We could also just as easily pass in a parent observable and not have to go get it from the manager, it just depends on whether we have it already or not.

Another way you could do this if you want to manage the entities separately is to save a single entity at a time with entityManager.saveChanges([childA]) as they are ready.  Just pass in an array with a single entity that you want to save.  This may be useful if you are working on multiple entities but they aren't all ready for saving and you need to navigate around your app.  Unless you call cancelChanges() Breeze will just keep the entity in cache until you are ready to use it again.  In this manner, just make a call for entities in the isAdded() state and you can pull 'em back in and edit again.

Comment: Your awesome clarification of the behaviour was essentially what I was doing.  The issue here was specifically how to handle it if I ended up not wanting to use ChildA or ChildB, and because it is attached to the entity manager when it is created, it would have been saved if I didn't handle it properly.  It turns out a simple call to delete it, detaches it correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Cool, if it answered your question and you want to mark it as accepted or upvote it I wouldn't mind : )